# "Whisky prices" in Italian

Tags: word-choice, translation

I am looking for the correct translation of "whisky prices". It looks like *prezzo* is singular and *prezzi* is plural.

Now I am wondering if one needs an article or a declension to form this phrase in Italian. I translated it as *whisky prezzi* or *prezzi del whisky*. Which one of these two forms is correct? Or is there another form perhaps?

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE, @osi!

Comment: I feel questions like this verge on the off-topic per [a discussion in Meta](http://meta.italian.stackexchange.com/questions/12/are-questions-about-translation-requests-on-topic).

Comment: @DaG: I think it's on-topic because the OP has provided a translation and he or she is asking whether this translation is correct or it could be improved.

Comment: I disagree, but you are a moderator and I respect your decision.

Comment: @DaG I too dislike lack of research or when people ask us to do their homework, but I think this one is on-topic according to that Meta post, it's not exactly a "plzsendtehtranzlation" question.

Comment: @kos: The Meta post assume for the question to «describe a very specific issue, for instance with the construction of the phrase or the choice of a term in place of another, and show some effort from the OP». Here, I see only two automatic-looking translations, but I won't insist further.

Comment: @DaG There's no problem in insisting as your point is quite reasonable, and I think it should be covered in that Meta post. In my opinion the problem is just that we can't state that is an automatic translation. However if you feel like this should be closed you should really vote to close, perhaps others will agree with closing the question.

Comment: You are right about the vote to close, @kos.

Comment: @DaG, I've tried to adjust the question to make it more on-topic.

Comment: My translation would be “il prezzo del whisky”. A more concrete phrase could be “the prices of frozen orange juice had large oscillations”, that should be rendered as “il prezzo del succo d'arancia congelato ha avuto grandi oscillazioni”.

Comment: @egreg. Right, or perhaps the OP meant the prices of different kinds of whisky, or how knows what else, without the context. It is almost impossible to translate two isolated words.

Comment: @osi Please, provide some more context, because otherwise no real answer can be given: the translation is different in different contexts. However, the problem is interesting, so a more elaborate question is surely welcome and doesn't risk being closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Prezzi del whisky* is the correct form, *whisky prezzi* is surely an error.

This type of preposition (*del*) is a preposition combined with an article (*preposizione articolata*) and is built by a simple preposition + definite article.

http://www.oneworlditaliano.com/english/italian-grammar/articulated-prepositions-in-italian.htm

Take care in Italian the word whisky is used for both singular and plural.

Comment: Benvenuto su Italian.SE, @Mike! Potresti spiegare un po' di più? Per esempio, perché "whisky prezzi" non è corretto in italiano? Qui ci aspettiamo una risposta più elaborata.

Comment: Aggiungo carne al fuoco: e se qualcuno scrivesse _dell'whisky_? :-) È interessante scoprire come mai _whisky_ si pronunci _uìschi_ eppure voglia l'articolo _il_, mentre l'unica altra parola italiana che inizia con quel suono, _uistitì_, voglia l'articolo _lo_. L'uistitì è una scimmietta che non beve il whisky.

Comment: Quasi quasi lo trasformo in un'altra domanda...