# "Un po' più" oppure "un po' di più"?

Tags: difference, prepositions, adverbs

Quando ho scritto il mio commento a [questo post](https://italian.stackexchange.com/a/6172/707), ho avuto il dubbio se dovessi scrivere "un po' più" o "un po' di più". Una ricerca su Google conferma che esistono queste due espressioni, ma non capisco bene quale sia la differenza tra l'una e l'altra. Potreste aiutarmi a chiarire i miei dubbi?

Comment: ...inoltre *fare una cerca* credo sia quantomeno desueto se non scorretto. Tant'è che Google è un motore di *ri*cerca!

Comment: @N74: Grazie! Faccio la correzione.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Bisogna partire dalla frase originaria, senza *un po'*:

> Corri più velocemente.
>
> Corri più veloce.
>
> Corri più kilometri.

Queste frasi diventano:

> Corri un po' più velocemente.
>
> Corri un po' più veloce.
>
> Corri un po' più kilometri.

Ecco invece un altro caso:

> Corri **di** più.

Questa frase diventa:

> Corri un po' **di** più.

Non è *un po'* ad avere due forme, è la coppia *più* / *di più* che fa la differenza. *Più* si usa per modificare un avverbio, un aggettivo o un sostantivo che seguono, *di più* si usa da solo. In entrambi i casi *un po'* ha funzione avverbiale.

Non si può dire *corri più* e non si può dire *corri di più veloce*, dunque non si può dire *corri un po' più* e non si può dire *corri un po' di più veloce*.

Tuttavia esiste una terza forma, strana ma non sbagliata:

> Corri un po' più di kilometri.

Ecco una frase dove suona meglio:

> Voglio **un po' più di** pasta.

In questo caso stiamo modificando un'altra frase dove *un po'* ha valore di sostantivo, cioè questa:

> Voglio un po' di pasta.

Aggiungiamo l'avverbio *più* **dopo** *un po'* per indicare che quel po' di pasta che vogliamo è aggiuntivo rispetto a quella che abbiamo già avuto.

Per quanto riguarda l'esempio portato da Charo, la forma giusta è sicuramente solo questa:

> Potresti spiegare un po' di più?